# Get the last path of URL

Tags: c#, regex, uri

I'm using the following code which is working just fine for most of the services but some time in the URL last I got **User;v=2;mp** and I need to get just **User**,how should I handle it?
I need some general solution since I guess in some other URL I can get different spacial charters

if the URL

```
https://ldmrrt.ct/odata/GBSRM/User;v=2;mp
string serviceName = _uri.Segments.LastOrDefault();
```

if the URL is https://ldmrrt.ct/odata/GBSRM/User its working fine...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just replace:

```
string serviceName = _uri.Segments.LastOrDefault();
```

With:

```
string serviceName = _uri.Segments.LastOrDefault().Split(new[]{';'}).First();
```

If you need something more flexible, where you can specify what characters to include or skip, you could do something like this (slightly messy, you should probably extract parts of this as separate variables, etc):

```
// Note the _ and - characters in this example:
Uri _uri = new Uri("https://ldmrrt.ct/odata/GBSRM/User_ex1-ex2;v=2;mp");

// This will return a string: "User_ex1-ex2"
string serviceName =
        new string(_uri.Segments
                          .LastOrDefault()
                          .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)
                                          || (new char[]{'_', '-'}).Contains(c))
                          .ToArray());
```

Update, in response to what I understand to be a question below :) :

You could just use a `String.Replace()` for that, or you could use filtering by doing something like this:

```
// Will return: "Userexex2v=2mp"
string serviceName = 
             new string(_uri.Segments
                            .LastOrDefault()       
                            .Where(c => 
                                    !Char.IsPunctuation(c) // Ignore punctuation
                                    // ..and ignore any "_" or "-":
                                    && !(new char[]{'_', '-'}).Contains(c)) 
                             .ToArray());
```

If you use this in production, mind you, be sure to clean it up a little, e.g. by splitting into several variables, and defining your char[]-array prior to usage.

Comment: HI Kjartah,Thanks voted up,there is a way to add some general solution for example if I have additional characters in the URL to omit them ,like in this case ";"

Comment: HI Kjartah when I use the update code I get in service name Userexex2v=2mp" when I use the link which I was provided ,how can I get just User? :)

Comment: @JeanTehhe You can adjust it as you need by changing the code within `where( c => xyz)`. Use whatever you need for `xyz` here, for example `Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)` to only allow for characters (c) that are numbers and letters, etc. You can combine this with the first example, or anything else you may need.

Comment: Note that the first example cuts off everything from and after ";", while the second one just filters away characters, depending on which you do or don't want to allow. You should be able to combine the two by using `Where(...).TakeWhile(...).ToArray()` if you need to go that far.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails for a relative URI.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can try to split a **"User;v=2;mp"** string.

```
string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] { ';' });
```

*Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character array.*

```
split.First();
```

or:

```
split[0];
```